# Thread 1 and 2 are taking much priority in my implementation of Lamport's bakery algorithm

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, pthreads

I am implementing [Lamport's bakery algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm).

My output shows that the threads 1 and 2 are taking much priority than others. My implementation is as follows.

```c
#include(pthread.h)
#include(stdio.h>
#include(unistd.h>
#include (assert.h>
volatile int NUM_THREADS = 10;
volatile int Number[10] = {0};
volatile int count_cs[10] = {0};
volatile int Entering[10] = {0};

int max()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int maxvalue = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if ((Number[i]) > maxvalue)
        {
              maxvalue = Number[i];
        }
    }
    return maxvalue;
}

lock(int i)
{
    int j;
    Entering[i] = 1;
    Number[i] = 1 + max();
    Entering[i] = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= NUM_THREADS; j++)
    {
        while (Entering[j]) { } /* Do nothing */
        while ((Number[j] != 0) &&
               ((Number[j] < Number[i]) ||
                ((Number[j] == Number[i]) && (j < i)))) { }
    }
}

unlock(int i) {
    Number[i] = 0;
}

void Thread(int i) {
   while (1) {
       lock(i);
       count_cs[i+1] = count_cs[i+1] + 1 ;
       //printf("critical section of %d\n", i+1);
       unlock(i);
   }
}

int main()
{
   int duration = 10000;
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long t;
   for(t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++){
       printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t+1);
       rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, Thread, (int)t);
       if (rc){
           printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
           exit(-1);
        }
   }
   usleep(duration*1000);
   for(t=0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++)
    {
    printf("count of thread no %d is %d\n",t+1,count_cs[t+1]);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

If I print some value in critical section, I get almost equal numbers of counts for all threads. Why am I getting this change in outputs?

Output without print statements in critical section:

```
count of thread no 1 is 551013
count of thread no 2 is 389269
count of thread no 3 is 3
count of thread no 4 is 3
count of thread no 5 is 3
count of thread no 6 is 3
count of thread no 7 is 3

count of thread no 8 is 3
count of thread no 9 is 3
count of thread no 10 is 3
```

Output with print statements in critical section:

```
count of thread no 1 is 5
count of thread no 2 is 6
count of thread no 3 is 5
count of thread no 4 is 5
count of thread no 5 is 5
count of thread no 6 is 5
count of thread no 7 is 4
count of thread no 8 is 4
count of thread no 9 is 4
count of thread no 10 is 4
```

To avoid problems with the memory model, I am restricting my threads to a single CPU and using `taskset 0x00000001 ./a.out` to run my program on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with this.

Firstly, `pthread_create` takes a lot of time: certainly a lot more than a quick lock/increment count/unlock iteration. Therefore the first thread gets a big advantage over the others, as it is running first, and the second gets a smaller advantage and so forth. When you stick the `printf` in the loop, this slows the thread down, so the advantage is smaller.

On a related note, just because `pthread_create` has returned, the thread hasn't necessarily started. It just means that the scheduler will now consider it.

Thirdly, your lock implementation is a busy wait loop. Consequently, it will take all available CPU time for whichever thread is running. Since you are running your code on a single core, if the thread that owns the lock is suspended then the other threads will spend all their time slices doing a busy wait, and then the thread with the lock can resume, unlock, try and take the lock again.

Finally, in the case of contention on the lock, this algorithm gives priority to the thread with the lowest number, so thread 0 will get the lock more than others, since all threads are doing a busy wait, and thus there is high contention.

Try putting some `sched_yield()` calls in the loops in `lock()` to allow the thread with the lock more of a chance to run.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are running on a single CPU so you are avoiding the following problem. Still, keep it in mind.

Note that unlike Microsoft's compiler, GCC does not give special non-standard SMP thread meanings to `volatile`. Therefore you cannot rely on it for ordering between CPUs. That means that if, say, `Number` and `Entering` are on different cache lines, CPU-0 is free to make writes to `Number` and `Entering` appear on CPU-1 in a different order than you thought they were written.

To solve this you need to use atomic operations. GCC has builtins for these.